# Successful use of strtol() in C

Tags: beginner, c, integer

Attempted to use `strtol()` to parse a string into an integer and to output any appropriate error messages for failed conversions. How did I do? How could/should it be done? Code works as intended if I did not miss anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 1024

void retrieveStringInput(char *str, size_t buffersize)
{
    for (;;) {
        if (fgets(str, buffersize, stdin) != NULL) {
            str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
            return;
        }
        printf("No input detected please try again...\n");
    }
}


int stringToInt(char *str)
{
    char *end = NULL;
    long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if (!*end && end != str) {
        if (number <= INT_MIN || number >= INT_MAX) {
            printf("ERROR INPUT IS OUT OF RANGE FOR INTEGER VALUE, %d < number < %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
            return 0;
        }
        return (int)number;
    }
    printf("STRING FAIILED TO CONVERT...\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char number[MAXLENGTH];
    int convertNumber = 0;
    retrieveStringInput(number, sizeof number);

    if (number[0] = '0') {
        printf("Your number is: %d\n", convertNumber);
    }

    if ((convertNumber = stringToInt(number)) != 0)
        printf("YOUR NUMBER IS: %d\n", convertNumber);

    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/143496/9357)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Compiler errors

First of all, this code does not compile with the (IMO too lenient) command line of :

```
gcc -Wall -Werror main.c -o strtol
```

Instead it gives the message that @vnp showed in their answer, that you should change `if (number[0] = '0')` to either `if ( (number[0] = '0') )` or to `if (number[0] == '0')`.

Having said that, the command line I usually use (and the one I put in my Makefiles) is:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Werror -fverbose-asm -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion --pedantic-errors -std=gnu11 -ggdb
```

With these arguments I get the following from my IDE:

```
error: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion] at line 15 col 24

error: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses] at line 45 col 9

note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning at line 45 col 19

note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison at line 45 col 19
```

Without fixing these, the program does not work quite correctly:

```
$ ./strtol
4
Your number is: 0
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
888
Your number is: 0
YOUR NUMBER IS: 88
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
11
Your number is: 0
YOUR NUMBER IS: 1
Press any key to continue...
```

Upon further inspection, the first character is ignored in the output:

```
$ ./strtol
623642
Your number is: 0
YOUR NUMBER IS: 23642
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
 435345345
Your number is: 0
YOUR NUMBER IS: 435345345
Press any key to continue...
```

Upon correcting the errors mentioned by the compiler flags, however, the bugs appear to have disappeared!

```
$ ./strtol
4545
YOUR NUMBER IS: 4545
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
 90
YOUR NUMBER IS: 90
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
asdasdasdadasdasd
STRING FAIILED TO CONVERT...
Press any key to continue...


$ ./strtol
9999999
YOUR NUMBER IS: 9999999
Press any key to continue...
```

Let this be a lesson to ye -- *listen to the C compiler, for it knows many things* :)

#### API

When I write in C, I try to make my functions applicable to a wide variety of uses because C is verbose, simplistic and lacks polymorphism.

Having said that, I'm not sure how I feel about the *interface* I find when I read your code. Because the point of this program is hardly an end unto itself, surely this has applications in other projects' `#include`s.

To this end, it would likely be best and most testable if functions didn't have rather unrelated side effects, like printing, which could be handled by the caller.

That is, however, quite subjective and your use-case may differ entirely.

#### Organisation / Style

I know you're using Windows because you call `getch()` without an `#include <curses.h>`, or perhaps that was a typo and you meant `getchar()` (from `<stdio.h>`).

So even though all the functions in `windows.h` are laughable with their `longCamelCaseCOMNames`, "idiomatic" C uses `snake_case_ndrscrs_and_abbrs`, not `camelCase`.

Moreover, in "idiomatic" modern C:

- `#include <stdbool.h>` gives us the much cleaner `while ( true ) { ...`
- a function purporting to call `strtol` (string to **long** int) should have type `long`, not `int`
- code uses the `bool` or `ssize_t` return type, or writes error to a pointer passed as an argument,  to indicate error rather than 0

  - this way, I don't have to have two `if` statements every time I want to use your function -- this is almost as bad as `atoi`.
- *always* use braces around if statement bodies -- okay, maybe this is personal preference but I think it misleads me and other people reading your code.

#### How I would write it

I've been writing a lot of C lately, so here's how I'd reimplement your idea.

Mine writes a lot less STDOUT, but you could make it do more with the information the functions give you:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 1024

bool    readln (char** buf, const size_t len);
char* conv_str (const char* const str, long* out);
void str_chomp (char* const str);

// read a line of STDIN
bool readln (char** buf, const size_t len) {

  if ( fgets(*buf, len > INT_MAX ? INT_MAX : (int) len, stdin) != NULL) {
    str_chomp(*buf);
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}

// try to convert a string to a number or return the erroneous part
char* conv_str (const char* const str, long* out) {
  char* end   = NULL;
  long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);

  if ( end != str && !(*end) ) {
    *out = number;
    end = NULL;
  }

  return end;
}

// cut the last newline or don't
void str_chomp (char* const str) {

  if (str && (strchr(str, '\n') != NULL) ) {
    str[ strcspn(str, "\n") ] = 0;
  }
}

int main(void) {

  char* in_buf = malloc(sizeof (char) * MAXLENGTH);

  printf("Enter a number! ");

  while ( ! readln(&in_buf, MAXLENGTH) ) {
    printf("\nEnter another! ");
  }

  long out;
  char* err = conv_str(in_buf, &out);
  if ( err == NULL) {
    printf("Your number was: %ld\n", out);

  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "That number '%s' was junk!\n", err);
  }

  free(in_buf);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I always assumed that ``-Wextra`` would cover about everything (despite there being ``-Wall`` which doesn’t do that). The additional warning flags you specify (some of which sound pretty useful, such as ``-Wstrict-overflow``) are not included in ``-Wextra``?

Comment: @JonasWielicki In the case of `-Wstrict-overflow`, `-Wall` only enables `-Wstrict-overflow=1`, which is not enough for me because I make silly mistakes sometimes -- I want `-Wstrict-overflow=5`. I don't see many others that are redundant [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) but I might have missed some

Comment: I think that the bit that prints "Couldn't convert this part" probably ought to go to `stderr`, rather than `stdout`.  It doesn't seem to be part of the normal output of the program.  (That said, it's not really a normal, pipeline-style program, so perhaps the distinction is petty).

Comment: @TobySpeight You're right, I guess, and furthermore that really shouldn't go inside `conv_str` at all because I talked about avoiding side-effects, but I feel like requiring `conv_str` to take a `char** error` pointer is redundant with strtol in the first place.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've updated my answer

Comment: `if (str && (strchr(str, '\n') != NULL) ) {` not needed in `str_chomp()`.  `str` is never a pointer to a string, so this test is only needed if the function needs to handle pointers to strings _and_ `NULL`.  `(strchr(str, '\n') != NULL)` is simple not needed for `str[ strcspn(str, "\n") ] = 0;` to perform correctly.

Comment: The `int` cast does quiet the warning in `if ( fgets(*buf, (int) len, stdin) != NULL) {` yet does not address the issue about the warning.  It is a remote niche issue anyways About thr best that can be hoped for is `fgets(*buf, len  < INT_MAX ? (int) len : INT_MAX , stdin)`

Comment: `if ( !(*end) ) {` is an insufficient test for `strtol(str, &end, 10);`  Consider input `""` will pass your code.  Use `if (end != str && !(*end) ) {`

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is _always_ 1.  Not needed in `char* in_buf = malloc(sizeof (char) * MAXLENGTH);`  If code wants to correlate to the type of `in_buf` then reference that type with `char* in_buf = malloc(sizeof *in_buf * MAXLENGTH);`  Less maintenance, easier to review and less chance to code wrong.

Comment: Comment mis-leads `try to convert a string to a number or return false` --> `try to convert a string to a number or return NULL`

Comment: @chux Thanks for your review, I'll update my answer in accordance when I'm back at a TTY. The only one of your comments I'm marking WONTFIX is `malloc( sizeof (char) ... )` because even though I know sizeof char is always 1, it is consistent with other malloc / calloc / realloc calls, and it reminds me this will be used for holding chars -- it's personal preference like the braceless if thing, but I like it :D

Comment: @chux Regarding `if (str && (strchr(str, '\n') != NULL) )`, as vnp noted in his answer, "fgets doesn't guarantee the presence of '\n' in the buffer (it only guarantees proper string termination). If the input string was too long, (so a newline hasn't been read), strscspn would return NULL". So we need to make sure there's a `\n` in the input before we chomp it

Comment: @chux I've updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

- **Null pointer assignment**

  `fgets` doesn't guarantee the presence of `'\n'` in the buffer (it only guarantees proper string termination). If the input string was too long, (so a newline hasn't been read), `strscspn` would return `NULL`.
- **`stringToInt`**

  `0` is a valid integer. Using it to signal error conditions is wrong: the caller has no means to tell if it is a legit `0` or an error, and a printed message doesn't help.

  Testing for `end != str` seems superfluous. If `end` happens to compare equal to `str`, it means that the very first character in `str` was invalid. If you still want to tell apart the empty string, it is easier (and I say cleaner) to test `str[0]` before calling `strtol`.
- **`main`**

  You should turn on all warnings. Any decent compiler immediately spots

  ```
     warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
         if (number[0] = '0') {
         ^
  ```

Comment: "If the input string was too long ... `strscspn` would return `NULL`"   Hmm OP is using `strcspn()`,  not `strscspn()` what ever that is.   If that is just a typo on your part,  note that `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` works great is `'\n'` does not exist. It does not return `NULL` in that case.  It returns type `size_t`.

Comment: OP's use of `if (!*end && end != str) {` is idiomatic in C.  "If end happens to compare equal to str, it means that the very first character in str was invalid. " is one of the reasons they are equal.  `"-+1"` `" (spaces)   abc"` are examples that the frist character was OK, but no conversion occurred.

Answer (score 1):

OP's range checks are wrong.

```
// problems
long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);
if (!*end && end != str) {
    if (number <= INT_MIN || number >= INT_MAX) {
        printf("ERROR INPUT IS OUT OF RANGE ....
```

If testing `int` range ...  (note `<` vs. `<=`, `>` vs. `>=`)

```
errno = 0;
long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);
if (!*end && end != str) {
    if (errno == ERANGE || number < INT_MIN || number > INT_MAX) {
        printf("ERROR INPUT IS OUT OF RANGE ....
```

Example [`strtoi()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259967/2410359)

Comment: See, I only notice these sorts of errors when it changes behaviour or causes warnings(errors) -- in the former case, I hopefully have unit tests, and in the latter case, I realise something grave has happened if what I thought was an innocent comparison warns me. :D