# Using strtol() follow up

Tags: beginner, c, integer

Link to original question: [Successful use of strtol() in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143257/successful-use-of-strtol-in-c)

After getting excellent feedback from the code review community I attempted to redo my string to long conversion program! I believe I enhanced it significantly(Most ideas from answers on my last post) but I did add my own 'style' to it and am looking to see if I missed anything or need to change the way I implemented the solution.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 1024

bool readline(char** buf, const size_t buf_len);
char* str_to_long(const char* const buf, long* out);
void str_cmp(char* str);

int main() {
    char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLENGTH);
    long cnvt_numb = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    while (!readline(&str, MAXLENGTH)) {
        printf("Try again...\n");
    }
    char* err = str_to_long(str, &cnvt_numb);
    if (err == NULL) {
        if (cnvt_numb == LONG_MAX) {
            fprintf(stderr, "INPUT OUT OF RANGE...\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Your number was: %ld\n", cnvt_numb);
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "That number '%s' was not convertable...\n", err);
    }

    free(str);

    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool readline(char** buf, const size_t buf_len) {
    if ((fgets(*buf, buf_len, stdin)) != NULL) {
        str_cmp(*buf);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void str_cmp(char* str) {
    if ((strchr(str, '\n')) != NULL) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
    }
}

//if returns anything other than NULL, conversion failed
char* str_to_long(const char* const str, long* out) {
    char* end = NULL;
    long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if ((!*end) && (end != str)) {
        *out = number;
        end = NULL;
    }
    return end;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `#include`

You didn't supply the contents of "stdafx.h", but I was able to compile simply by removing that include, so you probably don't need it.

You do seem to be missing a necessary include of `<string.h>`.

### `malloc()`

In `main()` you allocate a fixed length buffer on the heap.  There's no advantage over stack allocation (unless you're compiling for a system with a *tiny* stack), and no need to multiply by 1: `sizeof (char)` is necessarily 1, by definition:

```
char str[MAXLENGTH];
```

Also, I note that there aren't many platforms that support 3400-bit longs, so you could probably make the input buffer a bit smaller.

Having done this, your call to `readline()` can be

```
readline(&str, sizeof str)
```

### `readline()`

You take a pointer to pointer, but don't ever change the pointed-to value, so you could introduce a `const` between the stars, or (better) remove a level of indirection:

```
bool readline(char *buf, const size_t buf_len) {
    if (fgets(buf, buf_len, stdin)) {
        str_cmp(buf);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, it's not clear whether you want to return true for a partial-line read; it's probably worth a comment to clarify this.

### `str_cmp()`

You should remember the value returned by `strchr`, rather than recomputing it:

```
void str_cmp(char* str) {
    char *nl = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (nl)
        *nl = '\0';
}
```

I also prefer to write `'\0'` in preference to `0` to show we're dealing with string characters here.

Since it's only used from one place, we can inline this function.  It's a judgement call, but I don't see enough benefit from having this separate.

### back to `main()`:

This code doesn't do what it claims:

```
char* err = str_to_long(str, &cnvt_numb);
/* ... */
fprintf(stderr, "That number '%s' was not convertible...\n", err);
```

The value you get back as `err` isn't the string - it's only the portion after the parseable digits.  So for input such as `10x`, you'll just print `x`; it's not obvious that's what you want.  I'd show the whole string to the user:

```
fprintf(stderr, "That number '%s' was not convertible...\n", str);
```

You probably don't want to return `EXIT_SUCCESS` in that case, either.

You test for output of `LONG_MAX`, but not `LONG_MIN`.  Actually, both of those are legitimate outputs, so by not testing `errno`, you are unnecessarily reducing the range you accept.

There's a call to `getch()` but that's not declared in any of the headers.  Perhaps you meant `getchar()`?  Either way, asking for extra input just to exit the program is user-hostile, and I'd just excise that part.

---

## Putting it all together

Here's what I ended up with:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 40            /* supports 128-bit long */


bool readline(char* buf, const size_t buf_len) {
    if (!fgets(buf, buf_len, stdin))
        return false;
    char *nl = strchr(buf, '\n');
    if (nl)
        *nl = '\0';
    return true;
}

// returns NULL on success, or the unparseable portion of input on failure
char* str_to_long(const char* const str, long* out) {
    char* end;
    errno = 0;
    *out = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if (!*end && end != str)
        end = NULL;
    return end;
}


int main() {
    char str[MAXLENGTH];
    long cnvt_numb = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    while (!readline(str, sizeof str)) {
        printf("Try again...\n");
    }

    char* err = str_to_long(str, &cnvt_numb);
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "That number '%s' was not convertible...\n", str);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if (errno == ERANGE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "INPUT OUT OF RANGE...\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        printf("Your number was: %ld\n", cnvt_numb);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

It accepts input from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807` (on this system, where `long` is 64 bits), and correctly reports a range error for `-9223372036854775809` and for `9223372036854775808`.

`12345aoeu` is rejected with

> That number '12345aoeu' was not convertible...

Comment: `3400` is a magic number in the review.  Better to show  the basic relation ship to OP's `MAXLENGTH`.  (e.g. "... there aren't many platforms that need a 1024 `char` buffer (about 3400 bit `long` ).  My recommended buffer size is twice the number of characters needed to encode any `long`.   `#define INTEGER_STR_SIZE(t) (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(t)/3 + 3) #define MAXLENGTH (INTEGER_STR_SIZE(long)*2)`

Comment: Detail: 40 is certainly ample for 64-bit `long`. Yet `#define MAXLENGTH 40  /* supports 128-bit long */` --> 40 is insufficient for reading strings representing all 128 bit `long`.   Need at least ceil(127_value_bits*ln2 + 1 (sign) + 1 (\n) +1 \0) --> 42.  Recommend formula rather than fixed computed values.

Comment: @chux, yes, I failed to allow space for the newline, and for a possible leading `-` .  And our error-handling isn't great when the user enters an overlength value (really we should `readline()` until we reach `\n`, and discard that before re-asking).

Comment: This is kinda a review of [my review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/143268/87163) so thank you!